# The AMD fglrx driver doesn't see GPU cores in AMD APU A8-7600

Tags: drivers, fglrx, gpu, amd-processor, opencl

I wanted to play with [APU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Accelerated_Processing_Unit) meaning to learn OpenCL and other GPGPU tricks, so I've installed the [AMD APP SDK Ver 3.0](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/) (which implements OpenCL 2.0) on my PC. This SDK documentation says I need to install the [AMD Catalyst](http://www.amd.com/en-us/innovations/software-technologies/catalyst) (or `fglrx` driver) at first, which I did successfully after a lot of troubles. I used the archive from the AMD site, named as `radeon-crimson-15.12-15.302-151217a-297685e.zip`.

Nevertheless the `fglrx` driver doesn't see the GPU cores. The `aticonfig --initial` reports:

```
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
```

The `fglrxinfo` output is below:

```
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: nouveau
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on NV84
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.0.2
```

I know, this kind of questions were asked many times, but in my case I completely don't care about graphics, graphical acceleration, 3D graphics and so on. I just want to access GPU cores in my APU via OpenCL calls.

What can I do to get there?

Hardware configuration:

- Motherboard: ASUS A88X-PRO
- CPU: AMD A8-7600 with Radeon R7 (4 CPUs + 6 GPUs)
- Graphics card: some NVidia-based

Operating system: Xubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the Nvidia based graphics card?

Comment: @mikewhatever - my plan was to leave graphics to the discrete graphics card and do experiments with hybrid computations on APU. If I remove the  graphics card, what piece will take care of graphics when both CPU and GPU will compute?

Comment: It might be wishful thinking. Usually, when a discrete card is detected, the built-in one gets disabled by the BIOS. I've not see anything that lets you use both at the same time for different tasks.

Comment: @mikewhatever - I expected to see a command line tool which would be able to tell the `fglrx` driver: "Ignore this graphics card, focus on the APU". The `aticonfig` tool doesn't even show its help screen! Shame on AMD... But anyway, I'll try to switch my video cable to the onboard video and enable it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question - in case anybody needs the same configuration. After many retries I was able to achieve what I wanted - to have a machine with *hybrid* CPU/GPU processor, which is *not* involved into graphical output.

**Step 1**. I've found a motherboard BIOS parameter, which I needed to enable. On my motherboard (ASUS A88X-PRO) this parameter is on the path:

```
Advanced -> NB Configuration -> IGFX Multi-Monitor
```

**Step 2**. I've installed all the necessary prerequisites for the AMD Driver. On my machine they were:

```
sudo apt-get install dh-modaliases execstack debhelper devscripts xserver-xorg-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libqtgui4 lib32gcc1 dkms
```

**Step 3**. I've installed AMD Driver Ver 15.302. The driver archive has been unpacked into the `fglrx-15.302` directory, and the `*.run` script from this directory was run manually. The script has created four `*.deb` files, which have been installed by the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**IMPORTANT**: If you do the same, the script will ask you to run the `aticonfig` command. *Don't do that!!!* This command will configure the driver to use the GPU for graphical output - that's NOT what we want. Reboot after this step.

**Step 4**. I've installed the AMD SDK Ver 3.0 (release 130.136) in my local directory in order not to change anything in system directories. The `clinfo` command reports both CPU and GPU cores now:

```
$AMDAPPSDKROOT/bin/x86_64/clinfo|grep 'Device Type'
  Device Type:                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
  Device Type:                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
```

And now it's time to play with samples from the SDK...